# Apply .lyr Symbology To Layer Names That Meet if Condition

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, symbology, layer-file

I am trying to create a script that applies a layer style from .lyr file to layers in my table of contents that meet a certain criteria. The criteria being the layer name must contain string of "x".

Edit - This script now works for copying .lyr styles to layers that meet a certain if condition.

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
var1 = #Path to .lyr file
var2 = #Path to .lyr file

for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    if "TEXT" in lyr.name:
        arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(lyr, var1)
        print lyr.name + " identified as TEXT"
    elif "TEXT2" in lyr.name:
        arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(lyr, var2)
        print lyr.name + " identified as TEXT2"
    else:  
        print lyr.name + " did not meet the criteria."
```

Comment: Please roll back a bit further in your code and include the part where `layer` is defined, and include the diagnostic output of your script.

Comment: I incorrectly assumed `layer` would target the layers that meet the if condition. I'm trying to have my arcpy script look for `"string" in variable` then assign a lyr style to the layers that meet the `in` condition.

Comment: Did you get an error from Python, or was it masked inside a `try` block?

Comment: I think the first line in your `for` block should be to `print lyr.dataSource`, and the output from that should be part of what you report here.

Comment: I was able to fix my script and it now works